# event.preventDefault() not working.

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a method in my HTML.ActionLink and upon clicking on that link, a dialog is opened to confirm deletion of an element.  If the user clicks on Yes, the method in the HTML.ActionLink is invoked and executed. Else, the method is not invoked.  However, despite putting an event.preventDefault()  in my javascript function, the method is called when the user clicks on No.  Below are my codes:

Javascript:

```
function ConfirmerSuppressionPage() {
        var x = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");

        if (x == null) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        if (x == true)
            return true;
        else
            event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
```

HTML.ActionLink:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 10px; "> @Html.ActionLink
("-Pg", "SupprimerPage", "Section", new { pageId = @item.Id }, new { 
Onclick = "ConfirmerSuppressionPage();", @class = "editLink", style = "width:30px" })</div>
```

HTML output of the HTML.ActionLink:

```
<a onclick="ConfirmerSuppressionPage();"
class="editLink ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
href="/Section/SupprimerPage?pageId=70" style="width:30px" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">-Pg</span></a>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: adding event as parameter does not work.

Comment: Use only `return x;` in the handler. **Code:** `function ConfirmerSuppressionPage() {
    return confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");
}`

Comment: Nope, still does not work.

Comment: I would recommend not to use `preventDefault()` and `return false` together. Returning `false` do two things: **1:** `preventDefault()`, **2:** `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @Rohit416: Even when I remove preventDefault() and use only return false, it does not work.

Comment: try adding the `return` statement in `onclick` handler like this: `<a onclick="return ConfirmerSuppressionPage(event);"`, and do not forget to pass the `event`.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: @Sandeeproop:  Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 m

Comment: passing event in @Thomas answer it will work.
check https://jsfiddle.net/4tbrs7xv/2/

Comment: @Sandeeproop:  No the method of the controller is still being called.

Comment: There might be case that, there is some parent method is getting invoked. can you please try "event.stopPropagation();" instead of return false for eg. https://jsfiddle.net/4tbrs7xv/4/

Comment: @Sandeeproop: Still no luck here. alert("parent called") is not invoked either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95319/discussion-between-sandeeproop-and-user3762810).

Comment: @Sandeeproop: Yes ok

Comment: return false is not always the right thing because the form submit can take over if there is code before the return false statement. if you put preventDefault and stopPropagation at the beginning of lets say your Click handler the code after is reached with return false not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the event as a parameter from the function like:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll( 'a' );
for( var i=els.length; i--; ) {
  els[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) { //for this a / href
        event.preventDefault();
        ConfirmerSuppressionPage(); //do whatever you want in here
    });
}   


function ConfirmerSuppressionPage() {
    var x = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");

    if (x === null) {

        return false;
    }

    if (x === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tbrs7xv/3/

Comment: Non, this does not work.  The method is still being invoked, when the user clicks on No.

Comment: @user3762810 Will update it now, wasn't planning on changing his logic in the body unless necessary

Comment: It still does not work.  Any idea where I can check to see why this is not working?

Comment: because you have to bind the `addEventListener` to the DOM element of your choice. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: I don't get it.  Isn't 'event' bound to addEventListener here?

Comment: with `addEventListener` you (you might have guessed it) add an eventListener to an element. In this case the click event. Now calling `preventdefault` prevents the <a> tag to use the href and go to link

Comment: I actually meant, I tried the addEventListener solution, it still does not work.  Also, with event added, now each time I click on a <a> tag, a dialog is opened.

Comment: @user3762810 you cal `confirm()` inside `ConfirmerSuppressionPage()` that's why...

Comment: I have added event.stopPropagation(); and now the dialong is opened for that particular link only.  As for the main problem, I still can't find a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95321/discussion-between-thomas-and-user3762810).

Answer (score 0):

`confirm` will return `false` actually, so try this:

```
function ConfirmerSuppressionPage(event) {
    var x = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");

    if (x === true) {
        //some actions
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just `if (x) { ... } else { ... }` which would be the same in that case :)

Comment: Yep, it depends on the preferences

Comment: Note that the code in OP is always using `return false;`, here it is executing only for `else` condition

Answer (score 0):

you need to change for  pass the event object

```
<a onclick="ConfirmerSuppressionPage(event);"
```

and than here to get the clicked  element (should be used with event parameter:

```
function ConfirmerSuppressionPage(event) {
    var x = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");

    if (x === true) {
        //some actions
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got any error on console because i have tried it in fiddle it is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/pSS68/285/

Comment: No I get no error on the console.  Yes true your fiddle is working, but here no matter what, the method is being called.  Maybe it is because of the HTML.ActionLink.